# Pass value from loop to HTML - Django

Tags: python, django

My algorithm compares uploaded document with other documents and writes to output report like 'x part of uploaded document found in y document' and so on. Now I want to pass these reports to my HTML template but don't know how can assign value in for loop to some variable. Here is some part of my code:

`views.py`:

```
for each_file in files:
        other_docs = open(each_file, 'r')
        other_docs_words = other_docs.read().lower().split()

        for i in range(len(other_docs_words) - 4):
            for j in range(len(other_docs_words)+1):
                if(j-i == 5):
                    each_five_others = other_docs_words[i:j]
                    for original_each_five in iterate():
                        if(original_each_five == each_five_others):
                            found_count += 1

                            # This is the part that I want to output on HTML page.
                            report.write('{} part of document found in {} document. \n'.format(
                                original_each_five, each_file))

                        else:
                            pass
                else:
                    pass
```

Comment: Add the values `original_each_five, each_file` to a list, and then use for loop in [django templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something) to render the HTML part.

Comment: @BobReynolds They're not under any obligation to do so, you should be grateful that people are providing valuable advice. Also, your question could definitely be improved. _Now I want to pass these reports to my HTML template but don't know how can assign value in for loop to some variable._ You can assign a value to a variable in a for loop in the same way you would outside of a loop.

Comment: Am I correct that you want to see output of this process on the page while the loop is still running? Or you're okay with showing full output in the end of the process?